# Lsoda function in R

Tags: r, ode

To calculate the behaviour of my system of 2 equations, I use the lsoda function in R. The parameters a varies over time : is 1 when time is even and 0 otherwise. Here is a minimal reproducible example :

```
mo=function(t,x,m){
if(t%%2==0){
   a=m
}else{
   a=0
}
dx=rep(0,2)
dx[1]=-a*x[1]
dx[2]=a*x[1]
res=dx
return(list(dx))
}
xs=c(10,0)
ti=1:100
m=1
data1=as.data.frame(lsoda(xs,ti,mo,m))
```

The problem is that when you investigate the results, you see that x[1] remains at 10 while x[2] remains at 0, meaning that lsoda always take the value 0 for a (and never 1). Is it an issue with the modulo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lsoda` chooses its own internal time step, so there is no guarantee that `t%%2 == 0` will ever be true even if you ask for output when this condition is true (e.g., `t=2`). My understanding is that `lsoda` will interpolate between solution times to get output at the times requested by the user and not necessarily solve the model at those times. As a rule of thumb, hard temporal or spatial interfaces are a Bad Thing™ when it comes to numerical ODE solvers.

Comment: I tried to replace the condtion t%%2==0 by t<50, and you clearly see that from time t=50, the parameters doesn't equal 0 anymore. So, it seems that the time step remains the same. Do you have another idea?

Comment: I don't follow. When I use `t<50` it behaves as expected. Inserting print statements for `t` and `a` shows that when `t<50` then `a=1`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. So it means that the problem isn't only about the time step but also about the modulo function. One explanation could be that the time step used is not numerical. What do you think?

Comment: No, it is because `lsoda` is stepping over the time when `t%%2 == 0`. Put print statements in for `t`, `a`, and `t%%2` watch how they vary. `lsoda` steps over times when this statement is true and therefore it is never true. For it to be true the time has to be *exactly* divisible by two. As `lsoda` works to many decimal places this is more than likely never the case.

Comment: Yes, sorry I wanted to say integer instead of numerical. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly, time is not an integer. As I say, `lsoda` chooses its own time step regardless of what output times you specify.

Comment: One more question: suppose that I want to make the parameter "a" time dependent, as a vector where each value would correspond to a certain time. For example, in my model, the length of a would be 100 and a[50] would correspond to the value of the parameters a at time t=50. Should I round the value of t in order that it takes an integer value? It would give : a=vec[round(t)] where vec is the vector of the values of the parameter a.

Comment: I wouldn't define your parameter using a vector, but as a function using [approxfun](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/approxfun.html). Then, your model could call this function when it needs it, pass it a time, and get back a value of `a`. This way, you don't have to worry about time being an integer, etc.